# How to add indicator column that lists all values of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 'col': ['a','b','c','c','a','b','d']})

id  col
0   1   a
1   1   b
2   1   c
3   1   c
4   2   a
5   2   b
6   2   d
```

I would like to add a new column, which would contain the list of unique values of `col` by `id`

The end dataframe would look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 'col': ['a','b','c','c','a','b','d'],
             'col2': [['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],
                     ['a','b','d'],['a','b','d'],['a','b','d']]})

id  col col2
0   1   a   [a, b, c]
1   1   b   [a, b, c]
2   1   c   [a, b, c]
3   1   c   [a, b, c]
4   2   a   [a, b, d]
5   2   b   [a, b, d]
6   2   d   [a, b, d]
```

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lists remove duplicated values in order is used `dict.fromkeys` trick in lambda function and for new column is used [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['id'].map(df.groupby('id')['col'].agg(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x))))
```

Or remove duplicates first by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and aggregate `list`:

```
df['col2'] = df['id'].map(df.drop_duplicates(['id','col']).groupby('id')['col'].agg(list))
```

If possible use `ndarray`s instead `list`s use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['id'].map(df.groupby('id')['col'].unique())
print (df)
   id col       col2
0   1   a  [a, b, c]
1   1   b  [a, b, c]
2   1   c  [a, b, c]
3   1   c  [a, b, c]
4   2   a  [a, b, d]
5   2   b  [a, b, d]
6   2   d  [a, b, d]
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution with [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) :

```
df["col2"] = (df.groupby("id")["col"].agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
                  .reindex(df["id"]).values)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   id col       col2
0   1   a  [a, b, c]
1   1   b  [a, b, c]
2   1   c  [a, b, c]
3   1   c  [a, b, c]
4   2   a  [a, b, d]
5   2   b  [a, b, d]
6   2   d  [a, b, d]
```